# get line number of string in file C#

Tags: c#, linq

That code makes filter on  the files with the regular expression, and to shape the results. But how can I get a line number of each matches in the file?
I have no idea how to do it...
Please help me

```
class QueryWithRegEx  
enter code here


   
    IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> fileList = GetFiles(startFolder);  

   
    System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex searchTerm =  
        new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"Visual (Basic|C#|C\+\+|Studio)");  


    var queryMatchingFiles =  
        from file in fileList  
        where file.Extension == ".htm"  
        let fileText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file.FullName)  
        let matches = searchTerm.Matches(fileText)  
        where matches.Count > 0  
        select new  
        {  
            name = file.FullName,  
            matchedValues = from System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match match in matches  
                            select match.Value  
        };  


    Console.WriteLine("The term \"{0}\" was found in:", searchTerm.ToString());  

    foreach (var v in queryMatchingFiles)  
    {  
         
        string s = v.name.Substring(startFolder.Length - 1);  
        Console.WriteLine(s);  

      
        foreach (var v2 in v.matchedValues)  
        {  
            Console.WriteLine("  " + v2);  
        }  
    }  


    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");  
    Console.ReadKey();  
}  

static IEnumerable<System.IO.FileInfo> GetFiles(string path)  
{  
    ...}
```

Comment: Split the text into rows and match row by row?

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go:

```
var queryMatchingFiles =
    from file in Directory.GetFiles(startFolder)
    let fi = new FileInfo(file)
    where fi.Extension == ".htm"
    from line in File.ReadLines(file).Select((text, index) => (text, index))
    let match = searchTerm.Match(line.text)
    where match.Success
    select new
    {
        name = file,
        line = line.text,
        number = line.index + 1
    };
```

Comment: Since `match` isn't used past the `where`, why bother with `let`?

Comment: @NetMage - I like the clarity that it brings separating it to two lines. There's very little performance issue, especially since where doing IO here.

Comment: I understand, but I think clarity is less :) You create a reference `match` so I immediately assume it is used in more than one location and look for that...

Comment: @NetMage - It makes refactoring easier too.

Answer (score 0):

You can Understand from this example:

**Read lines number 3 from string**

```
string line = File.ReadLines(FileName).Skip(14).Take(1).First();
```

**Read text from a certain line number from string**

```
string GetLine(string text, int lineNo) 
{ 
  string[] lines = text.Replace("\r","").Split('\n'); 
  return lines.Length >= lineNo ? lines[lineNo-1] : null; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving the line number from a Regex match can be tricky, I'd use the following approach:

```
private static void FindMatches(string startFolder)
{
    var searchTerm = new Regex(@"Visual (Basic|C#|C\+\+|Studio)");

    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(startFolder, "*.htm"))
    {
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            int lineNumber = 1;
            string lineText;
            while ((lineText = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                foreach (var match in searchTerm.Matches(lineText).Cast<Match>())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Match found: <{match.Value}> in file <{file}>, line <{lineNumber}>");
                }

                lineNumber++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It works! 
But how can i also get the string? 
I need to show this string(not a match) I mean a whole block of text that matches

Comment: The block of text that matches is stored in `match.Value`... if you mean the entire line of text you can access it in the `lineText` variable